# angular (version 8) pass async @input value to fetch another call

Tags: angular8, ngrx

I have a parent component that has a button when the user clicks it will make a request and passed the data into a child component (a ngx-bootstrap modal). The child component will use the async data to make another request to render its UI.

My parent component is like this:

```
<Parent>
<child-modal [subSectionInfo]="subSectionInfo"></child-modal>
</Parent>
```

the subSectionInfo is async data retrieved from an ajax in Parent component.

My child component will make call like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   const id = this.subSectionInfo.id;
   this._fetchData(id)
  }

   private _fetchData(id: number) {
     this.service
     .getData(id).pipe(
     .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.list = data;
   });
  }
```

However, this always gives me undefined which causes the child component ajax call failed. Is any way to solve this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code does not wait on the first request to complete. While the request for `subSectionInfo` is being made in the parent component, it's value is undefined since the value hasn't returned from the server yet. This is why the child component get's `undefined`. There are 2 ways to approach this.

1. In your parent component, you can wait until the data is loaded and then pass in `subSectionInfo` to your child component.
2. In your child component, you can make use of the `ngOnChanges` life-cycle hook. This is where your child component implements OnChanges. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges).

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (changes['subSectionInfo'].currentValue !== undefined) {
      const id = this.subSectionInfo.id;
      this._fetchData(id)
   }

 }

  private _fetchData(id: number) {
    this.service
      .getData(id).pipe(
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.list = data;
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I took the first solution which works better than the second in my case!